# Add VM to Recovery Services Vault in different Resource Group

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm fairly new to Azure ARM Templates so any help it's appreciated.  I'm trying to deploy various vm's and at the same time configure the backup but I'm getting this error:

"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-' , 'BackupIntent')]' at line '195' and column '9' is not valid: The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "VnetResourceGroup": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "VnetName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "SubnetName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "OSVersion": {
      "defaultValue": "2016-Datacenter",
      "allowedValues": [
        "2016-Datacenter",
        "2019-Datacenter",
        "2022-datacenter",
        "2022-datacenter-g2",
        "2019-datacenter-gensecond",
        "2016-datacenter-gensecond"
      ],
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version."
      }
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "AdminUsername": {
      "defaultValue": "evtcladm",
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Admin username for VM"
      }
    },
    "AdminPassword": {
      "type": "SecureString",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Admin password for VM"
      }
    },
    "backupVaultName": {
      "defaultValue": "vault-corenet-01",
      "allowedValues": [
        "vault-corenet-01",
        "vault-cps-01",
        "Vault-Multi-VM",
        "Vault-RecoveryMultiVM",
        "vault-evt-cps-chile"
      ],
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Recovery Vault to be used for backup"
      }
    },
    "BackupPolicy": {
      "defaultValue": "FASE1",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "RSVResourceGroup": {
        "type": "String"
    },
    "backupFabricName": {
      "defaultValue": "Azure",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "VMNames": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "numberOfInstances": {
      "type": "Int",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Number of VMs to deploy"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "v2Vm": "vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;",
    "maxZones": 3,
    "nicSuffix": "NIC",
    "networkInterfaceName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'), variables('nicSuffix'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "name": "[concat(variables('networkInterfaceName'), copyindex(1))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[resourceId(parameters('VnetResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('VnetName'),parameters('subnetName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "nicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "nicLoop"
      ],
      "zones": [
        "[string(add(mod(copyIndex(0), variables('maxZones')), 1))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1))]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('AdminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('AdminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "[parameters('OSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
            }
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('networkInterfaceName'), copyindex(1)))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]"
      }
    },
    {
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-' , 'BackupIntent')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "resourceGroup": "[parameters('RSVResourceGroup')]",
  "copy": {
    "name": "AzureBackupLoop",
    "count": "[length(parameters('VMNames'))]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "virtualMachineLoop"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "template": {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('backupVaultName'), '/', 'Azure', '/', variables('v2Vm'), resourceGroup().name, ';', parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()])]",
          "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
          "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/backupProtectionIntent",
          "properties": {
            "friendlyName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], 'BackupIntent')]",
            "protectionIntentItemType": "AzureResourceItem",
            "policyId": "[resourceId(parameters('RSVResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('backupVaultName'), parameters('BackupPolicy'))]",
            "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()])]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in my environment was getting same error as you are getting.

[image]

***Solution***

please remove sqaure bracket from `[copyIndex()]` and seprate with `,`  for wherever you are using like below.

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'),copyIndex(1),'_','BackupIntent')]",
```

instead of

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames')[copyIndex()], '-' , 'BackupIntent')]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it now works but i'm testing it and when I create 2 vm at the same time it creates them but the backup part it goes ahead and creates like 9 objects saying:

       Microsoft.Resources/deployments/vmBKPtest1_BackupIntent' at line '195' and column '9'. 'The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated.'",
        "additionalInfo": [
            {
                "type": "TemplateViolation",
                "info": {
                    "lineNumber": 195,
                    "linePosition": 9,
                    "path": ""

Comment: Try with copyIndex(1) not copyIndex( )

Comment: Thanks for the reply, did a test with copyIndex(1) and it still happening. It fails with a badrequest, this time created 8 objects with the same error.

The is the object 8 with the same error but property 8
The language expression property '8' can't be evaluated.'"

Comment: Ok found out what was the problem creating a lot of objects it was the AzureBackupLoop I put in the count to use VMNames as parameters when it suppose to be numberofinstances.  Still getting the same error but now only with the number of instaces I input.

Comment: I think this type of template needs to be done with an array only.  I tested it out with an array and it worked.